# How to spot all transitive dependencies in mysql database design?

Tags: database-design, schema

I've read up on 3NF and transitive dependencies but had a couple of questions I'm unsure if I have achieved 3NF with my database design.

Context:
I want to create a basic bankings design where customers have required to give full name, date of birth, email, telephone number and opening balance to open an account. Each account opened will have a unique sort code and account number. Customers can open loans and therefore receive loan
payments from customers on a particular date every month.

CODE

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),
    UNIQUE (email)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE account (
    account_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,
    account_type_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    is_active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
    opening_balance DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 51,
    account_number INT(8) NOT NULL,
    sort_code VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    created_date DATE DEFAULT now(),
    branch_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (account_id),
    UNIQUE(sort_code),
    UNIQUE(account_number)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 

CREATE TABLE address (
    address_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    address_line1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address_line2 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    postal_code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    state VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (address_id),
    UNIQUE(postal_code)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE transactions (
    transaction_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    account_id INT NOT NULL,
    transaction_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    amount DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    reason VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT "n/a",
    PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE transaction_types (
    transaction_type_id VARCHAR(15),
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (transaction_type_id),
    UNIQUE(description)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE loans (
    loan_id INT,
    account_id INT NOT NULL,
    monthly_rate DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    duration_months INT NOT NULL,
    first_payment DATE NOT NULL,
    monthly_due_date DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (loan_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


Happy to answer any questions, and take additional feedback if my tables aren't complying with 3NF.
```

Comment: What bugs me about that table is _three_ Unique keys.  I don't know what "sort_code" means.  Do you give new customers £51 to open an account?

Comment: Previous questions: [Seeking advice on 3NF on my first database design for a banking system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/302710/seeking-advice-on-3nf-on-my-first-database-design-for-a-banking-system) and [Achieving 3NF in a online banking system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303131/achieving-3nf-in-a-online-banking-system). I think this is the best version of the question so I am allowing it to remain open for the time being.

Comment: @Rick James sort_code is what all uk bank accounts, is there anywhere else I'm perhaps not achieving 3nf that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

**Composite index is called for**

```
UNIQUE(sort_code),
UNIQUE(account_number)
```

-->

```
UNIQUE(sort_code, account_number)
```

(This is based on my understanding that `sort_code` or `routing_number` is a unique number for a bank or bank branch.)

**Unique is not called for**

```
PRIMARY KEY (address_id),
UNIQUE(postal_code)
```

-->

```
PRIMARY KEY (address_id),
INDEX(postal_code)
```

on the assumption that there are [potentially] many addresses in a `postal_code`.

> There are approximately 1.8 million postcodes in the UK and approximately 30 million individual postal addresses. Each separate postcode usually identifies the address to within 80 properties (with an average of 15 properties per postcode), although large businesses may have a unique code.

If you say `UNIQUE(post_code)`, then the table won't have more than about 1.8M rows.  The name of the table implies that you really want up to 80M rows.  (Yeah, your bank does not have a monopoly, but that is not my point.)  That table represents exactly one (or zero) row per address in the country, hence `PRIMARY KEY(address_id)`.

With `INDEX(postal_code)`, you can do `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE postal_code = 'W1A0AX` to find all the dozens of locations in that one post_code.

A side issue:  Decide whether to store the space or remove it.  Then do that consistently for both storing and searching by postal_code.  If you allow lower case letters, that can be handled by a suitable `COLLATION`.

**Rarely 2 Uniques**

Note: a `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` index.  `transaction_types` is one of the few valid examples of where two `UNIQUE` indexes is 'correct' for a table.  That table is a mapping between an `id` and a `string`.  I recommend you check all other uses of `UNIQUE`.

An `INDEX` helps look with performance in `JOIN` and simple lookups.  Both `UNIQUE` and `FOREIGN KEY` create a BTree Index as a side effect.

**Etc**

You seem to be carried away with `UNIQUE`; check all the rest of the uses in your schema.

(I realize this does not address your question about 3NF.  I think you will automatically root out the 3NFs as you work with the schema.)

Comment: Thanks, for postcodes why are we making it index exactly? doesnt unique give the same result or am I misunderstanding something? The reason I seperate Unique for sort_code and account_number is I've heard if you have the 2 columns in 1 Unique clause it means both on there own are not unique but together they are, however I need it so they are both unique on there own. Finally where have I used unique that you think i shouldnt?

Comment: @Mj_ - `UNIQUE(postcode)` says that there can be only one row in the table for each post_code.  I don't know how to further explain "UNIQUE"; please research the meaning for that term _in a database context_.

Comment: that make sense then to have postcode as unique, rather then index right?

Comment: @Mj_ - I added more on UK "postal_codes".

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean now I've changed post_code to index instead, I feel everywhere else I have used unique is justified, no?

Comment: @Mj_ - The tables `account` and `address` are the two places where `UNIQUE` seem to be misused.

Comment: cool fixed both the changes you've suggested make sense. On to my original question do my tables seem to meet 3NF standards based on my specific context? thanks

Comment: @Mj_ - Sorry, I learned SQL on-the-job, not from a text book.  I don't happen to see any of your tables with _two_ id-name pairs in it.  When I see such, I say "WTF, split this".  I don't say "that's not 3NF, split this".  (I spent some time on Wikipedia to learn what you were asking.)  Writing the `SELECTs` is the real test of a schema.

Comment: So does it look ok from your understanding? I just need a second pair of eyes

Comment: @Mj_ - `amount` is currently limited to 99,999,999.99 Pounds/Euros; is that OK?

Comment: seems reasonable, maybe 12,2 instead of 10,2 would be overall preferable?

Comment: @Mj_ - It depends on the bank and on future inflation.  To a lesser extent space is worth noting.  11,2 and 10,2 each take 5 bytes; 12,2 and 13,2 - 6 bytes.